# office UI fabric react in sharepoint web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-ui-fabric-react, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am currently developing a web part using the SPfx.

Wnated to know how can we edit or override the styles for office UI fabric react ? Thanks in advance.

**BreadCrumb.module.scss**

```
@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';

    .BreadCrumb{
       .textcolor{
           color:red;
       }
    }
```

**BreadCrumb.tsx**

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Breadcrumb, IBreadcrumbItem, IDividerAsProps } from 'office-ui- 
    fabric-react/lib/Breadcrumb';
    import styles from './BreadCrumb.module.scss'; 

    export class BreadCrumb extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);
    }

    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (            
            <Breadcrumb 
          items={[
            { text: 'aaa', key: 'aaa', onClick: this._onBreadcrumbItemClicked , isCurrentItem: true},
            { text: 'bbb', key: 'bbb', onClick: this._onBreadcrumbItemClicked },
            { text: 'ccc', key: 'ccc', onClick: this._onBreadcrumbItemClicked }
          ]}
          ariaLabel={'Website breadcrumb'}
        />
        );
    }

    private _onBreadcrumbItemClicked = (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>, item: IBreadcrumbItem): void => {
        console.log(`Breadcrumb item with key "${item.text}" has been clicked.`);
      }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `className={styles.BreadCrumb}` to <Breadcrumb /> JSX element. Place the `color:Red` in the `.BreadCrumb` css class

Comment: I tried this but it is not applying the style